# How to open mysql using batch file

Tags: mysql, apache, batch-file, command-prompt

I was wondering if there was a way to make a batch file that:

1) open a command prompt

2) go to C:\xampp\mysql\bin

3) execute command: mysql -u root -p

Please tell me if this is possible, This would help me save lots of time.
And if it is possible, what is the code?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Just create a `.bat` file,google it on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
cd C:/xampp/mysql/bin
mysql -u root -p
```

Make a .bat file, open it with the notepad, and paste that code in it.

You can check the basic batch commands by opening the "cmd" in windows (Start->Execute, or write "CMD" in Start's search box and press enter) and tipping "help".

Or you can google them.

Take in account that storing a password in a file IS NEVER SECURE. If your password will be in that file, it's susceptible to being read by anyone with access to that file.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed, and I'm only using this file on my local machine to be lazy ;)